# Please allow `status-declined` tagged posts in the `reqs` tab list

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, moderator-tags, bugs-reqs-tabs

Users will still come here looking for some of these features, and they'll just generate new questions if they don't find them.  This will also show the management what the users really want and the priorities of those items, even if the features aren't going to be implemented.

It will also keep the great sense of false hope alive, that these critical requests might someday actually see the light of day.

Answer (score 3):

As the [blog says](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/new-top-bugs-and-top-requests-on-meta/), this tab is supposed to be like a to-do list.

It's by design that all rejected feature-requests are filtered out from this list (and I happen to agree with that).

I do see your point about users coming along and not seeing things in that tab, but the truth is that those tabs weren't designed for use by random users coming along and viewing Meta. They're for the dev team.

Perhaps we can compromise and modify the tooltip description to something like "potential feature requests with the most votes".

Comment: Actually, if you read the `Bottom Line`, it implies that the tabs are for the users.

Answer (score 0):

If anything this is a request for the /ask page to get better at identifying duplicates.

And UserVoice -- because it *allowed* users to ask from the homepage, which is a horrible idea -- was always FULL of duplicate requests!

(and this is despite UV doing a proactive search for you on ask, as you type! Play with it here to see what I mean [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20090506031839/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/pages/general?))